# coverage calculations approach for clipped reads

Tags: dna-sequencing

Experiment: deep sequencing for mutants in 700nt fragment.
the fragment of dna was preamplified by primers flanking the fragment followed by hiseq.
per base coverage was calculated by coverageBed -d -abam in.bam -b ref.bed > out.cov

Observation: two distinct peaks in coverage at the ends as below plot.. coverage vs positions
[image]
the peaks are made from reads having part of primers..thus also show soft clipping at ends..
there is a huge difference in the calculations if i include such reads And if I exclude them.

Question: is there anyone who knows how to handle such a situation?

Comment: It's absolutely not clear, how you prepared your library for sequencing, where the boundaries of your primers are and what exactly bothers you in this context.